# Does usergrid support 3rd party integration?

Tags: integration, usergrid

Does Apache usergrid offer the ability to integrate with 3rd party systems via it's SDKs?

Specifically, I would like to be able to publish data from a 3rd party source such as an ERP system or CRM as a REST endpoint that is managed by usergrid. For example, if I have 2 paths:

http://example.com/my-org/my-app/my-collection

http://example.com/my-org/my-app/custom-source

I would like the data published on .../my-collection to be managed as a native collection backed by Cassandra, but the data published on .../custom-source to be populated using a 3rd party database or API.

Can I accomplish this without having to fork and modify the usergrid codebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively, Usergrid doesn't support this.  Instead of forking, you can use Apigee's API Services to create a Gateway/proxy which can route these two calls to different places.